# how to checked checkbox in pagination and search?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
  function checkAlluncheckAll(ele){    
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (ele.checked) {
       for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
           if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
               checkboxes[i].checked = true;
           }
       }
   } else {
       for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
           console.log(i)
           if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
               checkboxes[i].checked = false;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I have to create user list page in this page i put the checkbox for check all user but in pagination it not works.

in this page there is also search functionality if user checked all checkbox and then search then checkbox is also checked.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the relevant code???

Comment: You may want to read this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/641915](http://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/641915)